# How to use Flow Intersection Types on Arrays to extend an auto-generated type?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

[Please refer to this example.](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEEEFcBcHtQMYCcCmBDaKAmo0DscBLAWwAdYlMdYAjAKxQWgDoAoEUAYXz1mlBopEAC3wBzbGw4BlYbEgAbHINAoAHpgLZW0AJ6khAESSE8AawDOoALygA3q1CgOxfLtB9hKJKAvRIAGYBjgIo3hYAXBBISGi6ADwOAJA0sQRRfiZ4YiEAvgB8rLkhOvpCAKIaKFpYAEJhPrYOThaEAF4oUXiQxIJIRaylBqDGppaVmljYNiNZlqAAZPaC4VHgMXHxE9VTdQ35uc5gACrCSLAA7hYhTrd39w+Pt6wIsHh+oMS6o+ZRP+NVGozZqhVagADadlS+CwUQA5AAlTxoSAWOEAGl87U6oAADMwAKy5AC6TzJ5NAA1YX3+zBWSAszFcpAAFPSbPlQUhmK0OgBKI6gU7nK5RAAGvJQYuYoAACucDJR3Lx+AF5AQgA) I need to extend an autogenerated, unchangable type. I run into troubles when it comes to arrays:

```
// Auto created and imported object.
// Cannot be changed.
// Should be extended
type Drinks = {
  // many other stuff
  beers: Array<{
    brand: string
  }>
}

type ExtendedBeer = {
  size: number
}

type DrinksExtended = Drinks & {beers: Array<ExtendedBeer>} // Throws

const myDrink: DrinksExtended = {
  beers: [{brand: 'Rothaus', size: 0.5}]                            
}

myDrink.beers.map(beer => beer.size) // Throws: `size`. Property not found
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems flow does not support that kind of intersection of object types within generics.

This example works as expected

```
type beerWithBrand = {
    brand: string
}

type beerWithSize = {
    size: number
}

type beerStock = {
    beers: Array<beerWithBrand & beerWithSize> 
}

var stock : beerStock = {beers : [{brand: 'Rothhaus', size: 0.5}]}
```

Edit: this is the expected behavior because of the nature of the Array type (mutable). See https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/4258

---

Comment: I upldated the problem, your solution works but it seems not on my case.

Comment: I also updated my answer, please check the link to the github issue, ou may try importing the object you want to extend instead of importing {beers: Array<objectToExtend>}

Comment: Hm, I didn't get it. I'm importing the Drink object where beers have a brand. Now I need to extend those beers with a size property. Unfortunately, I couldn't find a good solution for this yet.